# How to pass List and other data from one screen to another in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I made an API call and returned a list data and few other values. I made the API call in one screen in the initState now and I need the list and other data in other 2 screens without Navigation. Is this possible. I am also using provider package. I am new to flutter so any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<YourClassName> list = [];
class ExampleProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  getList(){
     list = await yourApiCall();
     notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Your provider class should look like this. When your api returns, you need to use that equation. With that way you can call it everywhere your list with

```
Provider.of<ExampleProvider>(context).list;
```

Comment: When I do this I only get empty list. In my main.dart I have  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ExampleProvider()), under Multiproviders. Am I doing something wrong? I used for each loop to add data. Could you help me @burakaybi??

Comment: Can you add some code to your question to understand what you are trying to do